# Vue.js multiple root nodes when only one exists

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, vuejs2

I am writing some Vue.js code using a `v-for` loop. There is only a single HTML node within, but Vue is throwing two errors:

```
vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

<div id="products" v-for="p in productList">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                <figure class="figure">
                                    <img src="img/worship_area.JPG" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="Worship Area">
                                    <figcaption class="">{{ p.name }}</figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                        </div>

- Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements.


(found in <Root>)
```

and

```
[Vue warn]: Multiple root nodes returned from render function. Render function should return a single root node.

(found in <Root>)
```

My JavaScript is:

```
var products;
    $(document).ready(() => {
        products = new Vue({
            el: "#products",
            data: {
                productList: [
                    {name:"Worship Area"}
                ]
            }
        });
    });
```

and the HTML being referenced is:

```
<div id="products" v-for="p in productList">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <figure class="figure">
            <img src="img/worship_area.JPG" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="Worship Area" />
            <figcaption class="">{{ p.name }}</figcaption>
         </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm only seeing one  tag inside #products, but it's complaining about multiple elements. There is also only one element with and id attribute of `products` in the page, which is the one referenced above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it may look like a single root at first glance, the `v-for` directive renders multiple copies of it based on the looped variable. So the main root element must be something that is not loopable.

You can wrap your template code with another div and change your code to something like this:

```
<div id="products">
    <div v-for="p in productList">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <figure class="figure">
                <img src="img/worship_area.JPG" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="Worship Area">
                <figcaption class="">{{ p.name }}</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's just the same as my code with a blank div around it. From other answers, I've seen the ID attribute also be moved - was that the intended change?

Comment: My bad. The id needs to be in the root element here. The main thing is a div wrapping your code. That way there is only one root element and not multiple as will be created by the `v-for` directive.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap your html-elements into single root-element:

```
<div id="products"><!-- now, it is the root element -->
<div v-for="p in productList">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <figure class="figure">
            <img src="img/worship_area.JPG" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="Worship Area" />
            <figcaption class="">{{ p.name }}</figcaption>
         </figure>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```